# Detect type of string and create new variable accordingly to it

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse

So i have a dataset of passwords and i would like to create a new column if the password matches one of the following strings (im working with R)

```
id password   year     lenght
1  1 12345      2001       5
2  2 pass4      2002       5
3  3 angel      2003       5
4  4 pizza      2004       5
```

pattern for passwords with only letters: "^[a-zA-Z]+$"

pattern for passwords with only numbers: "^[0-9]*$"

pattern for passwords with BOTH numbers and letters : '([0-9].*[a-zA-Z])|([a-zA-Z].*[0-9])'

So basically i would need a new column named : TYPE with 3 levels (numbers, letters or both)

what I need is this :

```
id password   year     lenght   Type
1  1 12345      2001       5.   numbers only    
2  2 pass4      2002       5.   both
3  3 angel      2003       5.   letters only
4  4 pizza      2004       5.   letters only
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you are looking for. Can you show what your desired output would be like?

Comment: ok i put an exemple of the output i should get at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution. Just bear in mind that we put our conditions from the most specific (both) to the most general (either of the two other conditions):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Type = case_when(
    grepl("[A-Za-z]+", password) & grepl("[1-9]+", password) ~ "Both",
    grepl("[A-Za-z]+", password) ~ "Letters Only",
    grepl("[1-9]+", password) ~ "Numbers Only",
    TRUE ~ as.character(password)
  ))

  id password year lenght         Type
1  1    12345 2001      5 Numbers Only
2  2    pass4 2002      5         Both
3  3    angel 2003      5 Letters Only
4  4    pizza 2004      5 Letters Only
```

Comment: You're welcome. If it answers your question please consider accepting or upvoting.

Comment: I can't upvote yet since i created my account today . It's telling me i need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote

Comment: Thanks, no it doesn't matter. Let me know if you have any other questions.